# For loop jQuery, start over after 4 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm struggling a little bit with a for loop in jquery. I have a div with the class `.row`. Inside that div there are a number of `.item` div's. I do not know the number of items in advance.

What i want is to start counting at **0** and end at **3**. Like (0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3...etc)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row cl">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**What i've tried:**

```
$('.row > .item').each(function(i){
    for(i=0;i<4;++i){
       // Here i want to add a class (repeatedly) if the index of the .item is 3.
    }
});
```

The result in the above example isn't working properly. I'm getting 3's everywhere. I know how to add a class it's all about the counting part.

> I normally can use a CSS selector like `:nth-child()` but i need it to
>   work in IE 8, and that's not supporting all of the child selectors.

Comment: How about [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) ?

Comment: you don't need the for loop inside the each function (which is a loop)

Comment: You should add the word REPEATEDLY in _// Here i want to add a class if the index of the .item is 3._

Comment: @Royi Namir updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So much wrong in some of these answers

```
$('.row > .item').each(function(i){
   if (i % 4 == 3)
      // Add class.
      $(this).addClass("newclass");
});
```

Good night

Comment: I'm not down voting here either

Comment: This works! I knew i had to do something with the modulo. But many thnaks!

Comment: I love how ONE person modulod 3 - and it infected every answer!!! it was funny to watch

Comment: it's no big deal - everyone was complaining of downvotes, so I thought I'd chime in too - i really don't come hear for votes or praise or anything, I actually learn more than anything by browsing SO

Comment: Not the clearest question on SO, but by far clearer than most

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compare the `i` value with `4`:

```
$('.row > .item').each(function(i){
   if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
      // Add class.
      $(this).addClass("newclass");
});
```

Or you can also use jQuery's:

```
$('.row .item:nth-child(3n)').addClass("active");
```

Comment: you do realise that first piece of code is rubbish, right?

Comment: no it doesn't ... the first bit of code does a for loop for no reason and on the last time through the loop it adds the class EVERY TIME

Comment: @JaromandaX Check the `if` condition there. It checks for the index to be 3rd.

Comment: wow ... yes ... and on every iteration through .each, you clobber the i by using it in the for loop, so the class will be added EVERY TIME

Comment: @anyone give me one good reason to have a loop inside a .each here ))

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry sorry. I corrected. See the updated answer.

Comment: now it adds it to the fourth item only, not every fourth - you're getting closer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are resetting the iterator with your for loop. Do this instead:

```
$('.row > .item').each(function(i){
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) {
       // Here i want to add a class if the index of the .item is 3.
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it's possible but i need itto work in IE browser and IE < 9 is not supporting all of the child selectors

Comment: This is not yielding the right results. he wants 0,1,2,3. not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the index like this:

```
$('.row > .item').each(function( i,el ){
      if (i == 3)
          $(el).addClass("newclass");
});
```

Comment: actually there is a lot of difference, you have unneccecarry for loop inside a loop

Comment: except that will do it on the FIRST, FOURTH, SEVENTH ... not the FOURTH EIGHTH TWELFTH - other than that, the logic is sound

Answer (score 0):

As of what I understand you want to add a class to every fourth *div* with class 'item' under *div* with class 'row'.

You can use the following code snippet:

```
$('.row > .item').each(function(i, ele){
    if((i+1) %4 ===0)
    //Add class using $(ele).addClass();
});
```

Moreover, you can use CSS3 pseudo selector (nth-child) for the same. Let me know if you need help regarding the solution.

Comment: **you can use CSS3 pseudo selector** - you came late, so you should've seen the _I normally can use a CSS selector like :nth-child() but i need it to work in IE 8_

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add a class to every item with index of 3's multiple, you can use remainder operator like

```
$('.row .item').each(function(i){
   if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
      $(this).addClass("you-new-class");
});
```

Comment: because it looks like you copied an old (wrong) answer - not that I downvoted ...

Comment: The code looks like an exact copy of Dhiwa's code. That may be the reason.